# Trying to use Android Starage Access Network API to browse a folder without success

Tags: android

I'm trying to browse the content of a folder and when I find a subdirectory I then want to see get its content as well.

To get select a root folder I'm using the following code

```
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, FOLDER_SELECTION_CODE);
```

Then in my activity onActivityResult() callback I'm doing the following

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
    onDisplayFolderContent(data.getData());
}
```

then

```
public static void onDisplayFolderContent(final Uri uri) {
    final DocumentFile root = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, uri);
    for (DocumentFile file : root.listFiles()) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            onDisplayFolderContent(file.getUri());
        } else {            
            LogHelper.d("onDisplayFolderContent()", file.getName() + " * " + file.getType());           
        }
    }
}
```

The path I select is /Media, which then contains a subfolder Audio/ Which contains multiple subfodlers with files

The Uri returned by the folder picker

```
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AMedia
```

However, after the 'audio' subfolder has been detected, the Uri returned by the app is

```
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AMedia/document/primary%3AMedia%2FAudio
```

When calling onDisplayFolderContent(file.getUri()); with this uri, the same folder is returned and it goes into an infinite loop.

I have no clue where I'm making a mistake here. It looks like calling getUri() on the subfolder is not returning the correct Uri for some reasons

Comment: You're using `root.listFiles()`, but not using your `uri` that you were given at all. How does `root` and `uri` relate?

Comment: it's just a typo

Comment: uri.listFiles() will not compile. Please post real code.

Comment: `However, after the 'audio' subfolder has been detected, the Uri returned by the app is` Strange talking. Detected? Returned? You mean: `However, if the 'audio' subfolder has been listed, its uri is`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > onDisplayFolderContent(final Uri uri)

To make your function recursive change to:

```
onDisplayFolderContent(DocumentFile docFile)
```

> > onDisplayFolderContent(file.getUri());

change to:

```
onDisplayFolderContent(file);
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesn't change anything here. The fact is that for some reasons, when a directory is detected, calling listFiles on it doesn't list the content of that folder for some reasons

Comment: Of course it does. Please post your new code. In your post.

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesn't work, because this API fails to provide a valid uri for subfolders in a way that those subfolders can be used later. 
yes subFolder.listFiles() will work here, BUT if I want to keep the list of subfolders so I can check their content later on it will not work, because  DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, subFolder.getUri()).listFiles() returns the content of the parent folder...

Comment: Of course that will not work as you cannot use fromTreeUri() for such a child uri. And i only gave you code to recursively list a folder choosed with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. nothing more. Look at the title of your post.. . All you want more you only told now. Sigh..